# killing calling activity from child activity android

Tags: android

suppose app is started with activity A then from A call to B.then B to C then C to D.after starting D if user presses Home Key then again start app from launcheri want to start the app from activity A and if on B activity user presses back button app should close.Activity A should not b called..

Comment: It's a riddle... not a question. Very philosphical, should probably be at philosophy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Its simple if U want to call an activity you can use Intent. check the code

```
  Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

         finish();


    }
});
```

Here RegisterActivity.class is the activity which u want to call

Comment: actually my scenario is some diff i want to finish the first activity from the next (activity)..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't want to go back to Activity A again. In that case you need to clear the activity from history stack. While declaring activity in Manifest file set noHistory to true. see below.

```
<activity android:name=".A"
    android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: exactly..thanks a lot..but this solves my part of prob..actually my app has a splashscreen which is shown to user when user launches the app.first screen is just for 2 sec then a new activity is shown.and so on..what i want is when in the middle of using app if user presses home key and then lauches the app..it must start from first screen..i tried with activity property cleartaskonlaunch but it moves the activity to second activity..becoz i was finishing that activity when lauching second one..

Comment: now i want to start my app from first screen always..whether launched first time or second time..

Comment: You mean on back it should on go to First Activity but on Home Press it should is it?

Comment: its same as calling finish from activity A after calling startActivity(activityToBeShown).